# How should I get the absolute path of a configuration file to be published alongside a windows .exe?

Tags: c++, windows, resources, config, openvr

I'm making a windows application in C++. There's an API which requires a configuration file, and also the absolute path of that configuration file. ( https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/Action-manifest ). I would have an easier time reasoning about this if I understood expected practices for publishing an executable.

Should I package MyApp.exe in a folder named MyApp, with MyApp.exe at the root, and all resources/config alongside it? Does that mean that, when run, all relative paths referenced from within the executable should be relative to the MyApp folder? **How can I get the absolute path of the folder to which all relative paths are relative?** (Whereby I could get the full absolute path of the config file by simply concatenating that absolute path with the relative path of the config file, which I should have control over...)

edit: to clarify, the API *requires the filepath to be absolute*. See the link: "The full path to the file must be provided; relative paths are not accepted."
I'm not looking for c++ workarounds that would let me not *need* absolute filepaths: I need to find a way to get the absolute file path, because it is a constraint of the API.

Comment: In C++ you can use relative paths like "resources/text.txt" which will default check the resources folder inside the folder the binary is executed. You can also get the full path of the binary by checking argv[0] passed into main, orif you're on windows `GetModuleFileName`

Comment: Step 1) get the path to your executable (how to do that varies between platforms). 2) form a relative path to your config file based on the location of your executable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl if he's using a relative path from his executable, he won't even need the path to the executable.

Comment: @Nina That will look for the file relative to the *current working directory*, which is *not* always the same as the directory of the executable.

Comment: By default it should be the directory of the executable but I remember on windows there was a way to change working directory `SetCurrentDirectory`

Comment: @Nina It depends on how the executable is launched. If it's launched as `.\my.exe` then the two will be the same. But if it is launched as `..\some_dir\my.exe` then the CWD will be the directory you launched the executable *from*, *not* the one the executable is *in*. The same goes for desktop shortcuts. He *wants* a path relative to the executable, *not* a path relative to the CWD (unless of course the executable itself changes the CWD to its location).

Comment: @Nina - see my edit: I need the absolute file path. One way I could see that working is 1. get absolute filepath of executable (yes, NOT the cwd, but the executable itself) 2. append the relative filepath of my config file (which I should have control over by publishing my .exe in a folder- correct?). Another option would be to somehow get the absolute filepath of some resources directory that I'll be sure to put my config file within. (If I'm thinking about this wrong, please let me know! But I am locked into this API which requires an absolute path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it on Windows.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    /*If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleHandle returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).*/
    HMODULE selfmodule = GetModuleHandleA(0);

    char absolutepath[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    uint32_t length = GetModuleFileNameA(selfmodule,absolutepath,sizoef(absolutepath));

    //lets assume our directory is C:/Users/Self/Documents/MyApp/MyApp.exe
    //let's backtrack to the /
    char* path = absolutepath+length;
    while(*path != '/'){
        *path = 0;
        --path;
    }



    //Now we are at C:/Users/Self/Documents/MyApp/
    //From here we can concat the Resources directory

    strcat(absolutepath,"Resources/somefile.txt");

    std::cout << absolutepath;
    //C:/Users/Self/Documents/MyApp/Resources/somefile.txt

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Make sure you get the expected directory delimiters.

Comment: Yes I'm not on Windows at the moment unfortunately so the delimeter could '\\' but the gereral idea should work.

Comment: Yes. The only thing I do differently is pop the path into a `std::string` as fast as I can. Then you can use tools in `<algorithm>` or `<filesystem>` to help with the clean up.

Comment: @user4581301 if you could post a cleaner solution with algorithm or filesystem, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ah actually, I just came across this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fullpath-wfullpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019 <- is there any reason to not prefer the simpler (and stdlib) _fullpath API?